# Python sqlalchemy many-to-many relationship problem

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I have problem with sqlachemy many-to-many querying. I want to query items from many-to-many relationship with selected columns. I use Python 3.9 and sqlachemy >= 2.0.0.

Let's that we have model

```
ShopBookAssociation = Table("shopbookassocation", 
    Base.metadata, 
    Column("book_id", ForeignKey("books.id"), primary_key=True), 
    Column("shop_id", ForeignKey("shops.id"), primary_key=True))

class Page:
    __tablename__ = "pages"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    content: Mapped[str]
    number: Mapped[int]
    book_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('books.id'))

class Shop:
    __tablename__ = "shops"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name: Mapped[str]
    books: Mapped[List["Book"]] = relationship(secondary=ShopBookAssociation, lazy=True, cascade="all, delete")

class Book:
    __tablename__ = "books"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    author: Mapped[str]
    title: Mapped[str]
    pages: Mapped[List["Page"]] = relationship(backref='books', lazy=True, cascade="all,delete")
```

I want to have results in format:

```
Shop(id=1, books=["book1", "book2", "book3", "book4"])
```

I tried a lot different solutions:

Simple select:

```
session.execute(select(Shop.name, Book.name.label("books"))).all()
```

Some options solution like, but this return everything (including Pages objects):

```
session.execute(select(Shop).options(selectinload(Book).load_only(Book.name)).all()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the `Shop` table with `Book` and then apply an `array_agg` to the book names to get the result in your desired format

```
select(Shop.id, func.array_agg(Book.name).label("books")).select_from(Shop).join(ShopBookAssociation, ShopBookAssociation.shop_id == Shop.id).join(Book, Book.id  == ShopBookAssociation.book_id)
```